# multithreaded http server to take GET and POST from client browser

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, network-protocols

I'm trying to run a simple multithreaded server that fetches a URL and also that allows browser to upload file to sever( GET and POST ) it fetches the webpage with GET I'm having trouble with POST, here is my WebServer I'm using for making upload work. Note: HttpRequest is another class that handles threads

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;


public class WebServer
{

    public WebServer(int port)
    {

        System.out.println("starting web server on port " + port);

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

        try
        {
            //create the server
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        }catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("could not open port " + port);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        //loop indefinitely
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket connection = null;
                connection = serverSocket.accept();
                //accept the connection

                //create a new thread, start it and return to the waiting state
                HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(connection);
                Thread t = new Thread(request);
                t.start();

            }catch(IOException ex)
            {
                //fail if an error occurs
                System.out.println("problem accepting connection");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        //simple validation for the port number
        if(args.length != 1)
        {
            System.out.println("please specify a port");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        int port = -1;
        try
        {
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        }catch(NumberFormatException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("invalid port number");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        WebServer server = new WebServer (port);

    }

}
```

here is the Http implements runnable

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class HttpRequest implements Runnable
{

    private DataInputStream input = null;
    private Socket connection;

    private static DataOutputStream output = null;

    public HttpRequest(Socket connection)
    {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    //required method so this can be used as a thread
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            //try and get the streams
            input = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            output = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("could not get input/output streams from connection: " + connection.toString());
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder("");

            String request = input.readLine();

            System.out.println("request: " + request);

            String[] requestArray = request.split(" ");

            //read off and ignore the rest of the input
            //added so this can be tested with real browsers
            while(input.available() != 0)
            {
                input.read();
            }

            if (requestArray.length != 3)
            {
                //request should be of the format GET /index.html HTTP/1.1, die if a bad request comes in
                System.out.println("bad request: " + request);
                return;
            }else
            {
                //requested file should be the second entry, remove the leading '/'
                File requestedFile = new File(requestArray[1].substring(1));

                System.out.println("requested file: " + requestedFile);

                //check the requested file exists
                if(requestedFile.exists())
                {
                    System.out.println("file found, sending response");

                    DataInputStream fileInput = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(requestedFile));

                    //output HTTP header, must be followed by two new lines
                    response.append("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n");

                    String line = fileInput.readLine();

                    while(line != null)
                    {
                        response.append(line);
                        line = fileInput.readLine();
                    }

                    fileInput.close();

                    output.writeBytes(response.toString());
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();

                    Logger.writeToLog("Request: " + request + "\r\nResponse: " + response.toString());

                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("file not found, sending 404");

                    response.append("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n\n");
                    output.writeBytes(response.toString());

                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                }

            }

        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("cannot read request from: " + connection.toString() + ex.toString());
            return;
        }
        catch(NullPointerException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("bad request: " + connection.toString());
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            input.close();
            output.close();

            connection.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Can't close connection: " + connection.toString());
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail than 'iam having trouble with POST'? What do you see when a client makes a POST request?

Comment: it responds with a 404 file not found as if i'm requesting a GET

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your `HttpRequest` class is not implementing the HTTP protocol properly.  For starters, you are assuming that all requests are GET requests, and you are ignoring the header lines that follow the request line.

What you need to do is read the HTTP 1.1 Specification ... thoroughly ... and rewrite your code so that it reads and processes requests, and generates responses according to how the spec says it should be done.

Alternatively, don't waste your time reinventing the wheel (probably incorrectly).  Use an existing web container framework, or an existing HTTP protocol stack such as Apache HttpComponents.

Comment: how do i modify it to consider POST requests??